# Setting up DirectAccess on Windows 8.1

Tags: vpn

I've recently started using a new laptop for my job. My previous one had DirectAccess setup so I could access the company's internal network, etc. without connecting to a VPN. Unfortunately my new one hasn't had this configured and I'm hoping to do this myself.

However, I've no idea where to begin configuring this. I still have my old laptop if I need to lift some settings from there. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Good place to start? Google and Microsoft.... From MS: [Using DirectAccess](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/dn168168.aspx), and [DirectAccess in Windows Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn636118.aspx).  Where are you getting stuck Exactly?

Comment: The links you posted are the ones I've looked at already - they seem to be more centred on setting up DirectAccess on the server, not on the client machine. I assume, somewhere, there is a configuration along the lines of setting up a VPN where I can copy the details from my old laptop to my new one. I just want to know where that is, assuming it's that straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct access **requires** a server for functionality.  You can't simply set this up on a client if their is no DirectAccess infrastructure within the network.

Even if there is a server setup at your new place of work we really can't do anything to help you.  The setup requires a lot of configuration that is going to be unique to that network.  All the information about the network location server, direct access server, protocols, network ranges, DNS policies are only going to make sense for that single network.  Plus if they require certificate based authentication, there is absolutely no way you can get a valid certificate except through the proper channels.

So contact the IT support at that org.  Ask them if they have a DirectAccess setup or a VPN for you to use.